# Electorate badge description

Tags: discussion

[image]

The Electorate gold badge description says *'Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions'*

The word `questions` is duplicate and it is unclear. Let we change this text!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are changing the meaning with your suggestions. The meaning is:

- Vote on 600 **questions** - first requirement
- 25% or more **total votes** are on questions - second requirement

So for example, you might have made 2400 votes, and of that 2400, 600 are on questions (and therefore 1800 are on answers). This would meet the requirement for the badge.

Answer (score -1):

Vote on 600 posts and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Answer (score -1):

Vote on 600 messages and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Answer (score -1):

Nothing to change, this description looks nice.

Comment: I don't quite understand why your question says we should change the text, and then you answer saying we don't need to change it.

Comment: This is a kind of discussion. Check (vote) one answer you prefer to introduce at this description. Or write another, 4th answer.